# Ito Integral distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-integrals

Given a process $\sigma_s$ which is cadlag and adapted I need to prove the following identity in law

$$
\int_a^b\sigma_s\,dW_s \stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=}U\cdot\left(\int_a^b\sigma_s^2\,ds\right)^{1/2},\quad W=\text{ Brownian motion}
$$

with $U\sim\text{N}(0,1)$. I think that this should be almost obvious given the definition of stochastic integration, but now I cannot see it anymore.

A possible solution could be: (I am attaching screenshot of my own pdf)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you assume that $\sigma_s$ is deterministic....?

Comment: No, for a generic  cadlag and adapted so that $\int_a^b\sigma_s\,dW_s$ is a martingale.

Comment: Nevertheless it's ok for me to show that the identity is true conditional on the volatility path.

Comment: So you assume that $\sigma$ and $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are independent...? Because, in general, you can't simply condition on $\sigma$...

Comment: Yes, with independence between $\sigma$ and $W$.

Comment: Could I use the fact that, the (conditional) identity is for sure sure for simple functions and then the fact that L^2-convergence implies convergence in distribution?

Comment: That's a possible approach. Why not simply give it a try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55133/discussion-between-almostsureuser-and-saz).